# TortoiseSVN current baseline version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any way to figure out the checked out baseline version in TortoiseSVN?

That is, say I had checked out HEAD revision started working, there were a few checkins later. How do I find out the baseline version number that I am working on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several ways to get that revision number:

With TortoiseSVN:

- Check-for-modification dialog. Show unmodified items. Then you can see on the bottom left a label "Lowest shown revision" and "Highest shown revision" - the highest shown revision is the one you want.
- with a nightly build (upcoming 1.7 version) the log dialog shows that revision in bold, so it's easily visible.

You can also use the [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) tool (installed with TSVN):

```
SubWCRev.exe path\to\workingcopy
```

will output the information you need on the command line.

Or with the command line client, you could run

```
svnversion path/to/workingcopy
```

to get the same information.